# Use the same bootstrap modal to both add a new object and edit that object

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I have a Rails app where I'm adding new objects to a parent Object using Bootstrap modals and Jquery. This now works fine for the 4 different child objects I wish to add (I have 4 separate modals rendered on the parent object page). I'd like to re-use the same modals to render the edit form (rather than the new form), without adding 4 extra (mostly identical) modals to my page. Is this possible?

Modal example:

```
<!-- modal for inputting a new company -->
<div class="modal fade" id="company_modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="company_modal" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
          <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Add new company</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <%= render 'companies/modal' %>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Companies/Modal code:

```
<%= form_for(@company, :html => {role: :form, 'data-model' => 'company'}, remote: true) do |f| %>
        <% if @company.errors.any? %>
          <div id="error_explanation">
            <h2><%= pluralize(@company.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this company from being saved:</h2>

            <ul>
            <% @company.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
              <li><%= message %></li>
            <% end %>
            </ul>
          </div>
        <% end %>
     <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :company_name, :class => "control-label" %></br>
         <%= f.text_field :company_name, :class => 'form-control' %>
         <span class="help-block"></span>
      </div>
        <div class="checkbox input">
            <label>
            <%= f.check_box :existing_customer %> Existing Customer?
            </label>
        </div>
      <div id="organization_id" data-organizationid="<%= @current_user.organization.id %>">
        <%= f.hidden_field :organization_id%>
      </div>
      <div class="actions">
        <%= f.submit "Save", class: "btn btn-sm btn-success" %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
```

Current Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#competitor_modal').on('show');
 $('.modal').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
$("#competitor_competitor_name").focus();
var Org;
Org = $('#organization_id').attr('data-organizationid');
 //pass the organization_id to the hidden text box
$('#competitor_organization_id').val(Org);
});
});

$(document).ready(function(){

  $(document).bind('ajaxError', 'form#new_competitor', function(event, jqxhr, settings, exception){

// note: jqxhr.responseJSON undefined, parsing responseText instead
$(event.data).render_form_errors( $.parseJSON(jqxhr.responseText) );

 });

});
```

I presume I'd have to change the Javascript used in Organization.js so that it could determine whether the request has come from the "Add new company" button or whether it's come from the "Edit company" button. Is this best practice or am I just being an idiot?

Answer (score 1):

I think your idea is in the right direction and NO, you are not an idiot :)

Presonally I would think about following:

1. clear content of #company_modal - leaving just "skeleton" - placers for content that we want to manipulate dynamically,
2. write a common JQ function for rendering modal window (allowing all parameters such as title, content, buttons,...
3. write JQ functions for create/read/update/delete (CRUD) calling same JQ modal rendering function with different parameters and different actions,
4. write functions that delegate events and actions (assign actions to dynamic buttons in modal that allow calling functions for CRUD.

It seems a lot but I think it's way better and modular than just creating different modals for different actions etc.

But one must plan it really good (what would be exact look and feel, what fields, what variables,...)

Comment: Thanks. I am currently wondering whether it makes more sense for me to develop all of this or just use x-editable. On the one hand I think the common use of Modals (for adding AND editing) would make the user experience more consistent, and on the other it looks as though a lot of these issues have been solved already using the plugin. I appreciate the answer in any case!

Comment: Thanks, yes if some plugin that supports what you want (and is well documented) already exists - go for it :) Sometimes it's the best way (if we don't need some "special" functionalities)....

Answer (score 0):

Answer to one of your questions, "determine whether the request has come from the "Add new company" button or whether it's come from the "Edit company" would be to use

```
params[:controller]
params[:action]
```

to determine the controller action targeted.
Or use a session variable or some `param[:from_where_name]` and check it in the js. Worst case use a hidden field or some `data-field` to pass the desired value.